# how to implement push notifications from the client side

Tags: javascript, websocket, notifications, frontend, push

how can i add push notifications in web application if i have no access to the server side? all i have is API which sends me JSON like {from: '...', message: '...'} and i want to enable push notifications for it. the connection is websocket based. i do not want to display them when the page is closed but just when the tab is not active, or browser is minimized. what is the best solution to do so. i want it to be as native as possible. will appreciate ur help so much. im using react-redux, if that will somehow helpe he-he
Thank you!